# View loaded from nib not resizing correctly when embedded in container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nib, uicontainerview

I have a couple of view controllers/views with complex nibs I would like to reuse in different projects.  I am attempting to do this by building a container view controller in my new project and embedding the view controller in the container.  The view is being loaded from the nib in my project.

Although my original project is more complex, I have built a sample project to illustrate the problems I am having.  The sample project has classes and files as described below

1) CSMSketchView (.h and .m) -- allows the user to draw on the screen

2) CSMSketchViewController (.h and .m) -- used to control the sketch view and manage undo/redo/clear buttons.

3) CSMSketchViewController.xib -- contains the layout information for the sketch view

In the xib file, the undo/redo/clear buttons are placed in a container view with empty spacer views between them as shown below. The orange and yellow boxes are spacer views and the blue on the right is the end of the container view.  I have also added buttons on the left, right and bottom of the xib.  There are autolayout constraints keeping these buttons centered and 20 away from the edge of the view.  There are also autolayout constraints pinning the line of buttons and views in the container view to the container view, while allowing the width of the spacer views to fluctuate.

[image: xib file layout]

My main storyboard has one view with a CSMSketchViewController embedded in a container view as shown below.

[image]

When I run the program the views are laid out as shown below.

[image]

There are two problems -- the container view with the buttons does not stretch as it should, and the button that should be at the bottom of the view is at the top of the view.  I have done some research and watched a few of the videos from WWDC 2012 and come to the conclusion that the CSMSketchView owned by the CSMSketchView controller is not being resized after it is embedded in the container view.

My thought is that I need to add a line or two of code to instruct the CSMSketchView to resize it's frame after it is embedded in the container.  Unfortunately, I am not sure which line(s) of code are appropriate or where to add the code.

Comment: Are you using autolayout or autoresizingmasks?

Comment: Using autolayout.  All of the autolayout constraints are added in interface builder.

Comment: Have you tried layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: I had not.  I just tried adding that line in perpareForSegue.  It did not make any visible changes to the layout, but that may be the wrong place to put the code.    I also just noticed that the CSMSketchView is not being added to the main view controller's view hierarchy in code, which could be why it is not being resized.  I am new to this and I could not find a recipe/tutorial, so I am probably making an unusual mistake.

Comment: I just remembered that sketch view is inheriting from UIScrollView, when I change it to inherit from UIView, the problem is solved. I think I need to modify the size of the content view.

Comment: You probably need to set it's size equal to its content size.